# PHP: unicode and multibyte operations

Tags: php, character-encoding

I have a Korean Unicode string (`...입니다.<br /><br />소재...`) that I want to split between the `<br>` tags. I was foolishly using regular string operators, like `substr()` and `strpos()` before realizing there were `mb_*()` functions.. What I have is below.

```
$str = `...입니다.<br /><br />소재...`; 
$k = mb_strrpos($str, '<br /><br />');  // want the last match
$firstPortion = mb_substr($str, 0, $k);
```

However, it still doesn't seem to work. `$firstPortion` ends up being either the entire original string or some random portion of the original string. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work. Well, after you use quotes instead of the [shell_exec operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php)(notice you used back ticks ` instead of single quotes ')

regardless, the regular string functions should work too, so long as the data is encoded as unicode, and the strings you're searching for are just ascii, and `<br />` is ascii. otherwise there's edge cases that may occur in some encodings.

Comment: When I use the regular function (`substr` and `strpos`), it does find the right place. However, when I use `substr()` to extract the first and last portions and write them to a text file, they come out broken. Using `mb_substr()` seems to prevent that. I have a header at the beginning on my PHP code as well: `header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
`.

Comment: I think I've tried `strpos()` then `mb_substr()`, too, but I forget.. I should try that again.

Comment: dont mix the regular and mb_ versions, the regular version consider 1 byte to be a "character", while the mb_ versions may consider multiple bytes as one character, so their positions and offsets aren't compatible. You should also specify an encoding to the mb_ functions. Anyway, http://codepad.org/8VQLKIMZ